# Cypress hangs in Jenkins sometimes

Tags: jenkins, cypress

Cypress use to Successfully in Jenkins. From few week Cypress spec file it will hang forever. It will hang at different spec file, which makes it hard to debug and find why it is failing. Sometimes it will run all spec files successfully. Please help me out.

---

package.json

```
{
  "name": "budgeting-web-automation-cypress",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "e2e": "cypress open",
    "cy:run": "node scripts/cypress.js",
    "cy": "cypress run --headed"
  },
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "cypress": "^3.1.4",
    "mocha": "5.2.0",
    "mochawesome": "^3.1.1",
    "mochawesome-merge": "^1.0.5",
    "mochawesome-report-generator": "^3.1.5"
  }
}
```

---

cypress.json

```
{
  "baseUrl": "https://stg.Url.of.the.project",
  "viewportWidth": 1280,
  "viewportHeight": 720,
  "chromeWebSecurity": false,
  "pageLoadTimeout":300000,
  "numTestsKeptInMemory": 0,
  "video":false,
  "defaultCommandTimeout": 20000,
  "reporter": "mochawesome",
  "reporterOptions": {
    "reportDir": "mochawesome-report",
    "overwrite": false,
    "html": false,
    "json": true
  },
  "testFiles":  "**/*.spec.js"
}
```

---

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issues when running tests on firefox and chrome. It was also random.  I found that running them in a headless mode is much better and you will not face such issues.

For example, the below commands hangs intermittently

`npx cypress run --browser chrome`

but

`npx cypress run --browser chrome --headless` works fine

Comment: That's interesting because `cypress run` uses --headless as default so not sure what will be causing the difference in result